AppImages not running through Cinnamenu Mint Wilma
So yesterday I freshly installed my system (Linux Mint Wilma) and could open the AppImage in question from cinnamenu and grouped-windows-list.
Today it's not possible anymore.
The AppImage itself works fine, I can open it from nemo and the terminal, but not with a starter from menu or windows-list.
Any advice appreciated.
